Summarize each second in a timeseries with MongoDB with gap-filling
We have thousands of IoT devices sending measurements throughout the day. This is being stored in a MongoDB instance as a simple timeseries, with a value, a timestamp and an identifier.
Example data could look like this:
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-04-03T16:52:56.217Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "xyz",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "....."
  },
  "value": 100
}

We need to be able to make a report down to each second throughout a given day, with the sum of consumption from each device.
Some examples of the data:
DeviceA:
16:52:56 : 100watt
17:01:15 : 0watt

DeviceB:
16:56:30 : 50watt
16:58:38 : 100watt
17:00:04 : 0watt

This is interpreted as "DeviceA used 100watt each second between 16:52:56 and 17:01:15 and DeviceB used 50watt each second from 16:56:30 until 16:58:38 where it ramps up to 100watt each second until 17:00:04"
The calculation for these two devices would be:
16:52:56 : 100watt
16:52:57 : 100watt
...
16:56:30 : 150watt
16:56:31 : 150watt
...
16:58:38 : 200watt
16:58:39 : 200watt
...
17:00:04 : 100watt
17:00:05 : 100watt
...
17:01:15 : 100watt
17:01:16 : 0watt


Our initial thought was to use $densify and $fill, but you quickly realize that the about of documents get too big for this to be performant. Lets say we have 5000 devices each day, when running $densify, this would give us 5000 * 60 * 60 * 24: 432.000.000 documents in the calculation each day - only increasing with more devices being added. $densify bails out at 500.000 documents with default settings, and could maybe be increased while we're taking smaller chunks, but it's not really viable for a scaleable solution.
The other solution we're thinking about would be to use $shift making each document a span from one timestamp to another with the value between these timestamps. Given the above example, we would end up with something like this:
// timestamps slimmed down to only hour, minute and seconds
{
 from: null,
 until: "16:56:30",
 value: 0
}
{
 from: "16:56:30",
 until: "16:58:38",
 value: 50
},
{
 from: "16:58:38",
 until: "17:00:04",
 value: 100
},
{
 from: "17:00:04",
 until: null,
 value: 0
}

From this, we then need to (preferable in MongoDB) calculate each second in a loop, picking out the measurements with some sort of "between timestampA and timestampB" lookup.
The first solution would be something like this:
[
  {
    $densify:
      /*
       * gap-filling with per seconds, in the period
       */
      {
        field: "from",
        partitionByFields: ["snid"],
        range: {
          step: 1,
          unit: "second",
          bounds: [
            ISODate("2024-05-23T01:00:00Z"),
            ISODate("2024-05-23T01:01:00Z") // Notice 1 minute gap only
          ]
        }
      }
  },
  {
    $fill:
      /*
       * filling the missing values using locf
       */
      {
        partitionByFields: ["snid"],
        sortBy: {
          from: 1
        },
        output: {
          value: {
            method: "locf"
          }
        }
      }
  },
  {
    $group:
      /**
       * _id: The id of the group.
       * fieldN: The first field name.
       */
      {
        _id: "$from",
        sum_power_w: {
          $sum: "$value"
        }
      }
  }
]

The second solution would use something like this, and then afterwards either be handled in application layer, or with MongoDB, if someone knows how:
[
  ...,
  {
    $setWindowFields:
      /*
       * calculate the end timestamp of each reading
       */
      {
        partitionBy: "$_id.snid",
        sortBy: {
          "_id.from": 1
        },
        output: {
          until: {
            $shift: {
              output: "$_id.from",
              by: 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
]

So the question is:
How do you handle this size of interpolation in MongoDB?
And... Is it possible to calculate solution 2 in MongoDB alone (without the application layer)?
Hope this makes sense - if not, please let me know so I can provide the needed information.
UPDATE:
Added sample data.
[{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:53:40.396Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ123456",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "value": 1273.979,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f749a092659a0b468914e"
  }
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:53:04.253Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ654321",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "value": 2204.606,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f7472092659a0b4689134"
  }
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:53:12.272Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ654321",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "value": 2146.411,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f747a092659a0b468913e"
  }
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:54:33.282Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ654321",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "value": 2048.367,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f74cb092659a0b4689166"
  }
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:57:41.292Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ654321",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "value": 1850.317,
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f7587092659a0b46891af"
  }
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:53:10.731Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ321123",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f7477092659a0b468913a"
  },
  "value": 0
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:54:02.184Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ321123",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f74aa092659a0b4689153"
  },
  "value": 1218.115
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:54:07.244Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ321123",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f74af092659a0b4689157"
  },
  "value": 4309.275
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:54:12.304Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ321123",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f74b4092659a0b4689159"
  },
  "value": 8790.988
},
{
  "observed_at": {
    "$date": "2024-05-23T16:54:17.364Z"
  },
  "meta": {
    "snid": "XYZ321123",
    "type": "total_charge_power"
  },
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "664f74b9092659a0b468915c"
  },
  "value": 10662.279
}]


Edit your question to post the example data in the format you've given. Providing a structure separately from the data means we need to copy-paste all parts repeatedly and construct an example dataset before we can even start writing a query/agg pipeline for this. Do something like db.collection.find({ observed_at: { $gte: ISODate("2024-04-03T16:52:56.217Z") } }).limit(10) and export as JSON, paste here.

@aneroid I've added some samples as requested. Only changed snid to something random. In this case, when theres no zero reading, it should add it's value to each second in the given time-period.
